# What is a Perfect Inquirey Word™?

Tags: computer-puzzle, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Perfect Inquirey Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.
*Bonus*: Which one of the words is a Mega Perfect Inquirey Word™?

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Perfect Inquirey }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  ABDICATED }&\text{ ABDICATE }\\ \hline
\text{  BOOGERS}&\text{ BOOGER}\\ \hline
\text{  BOSSY}&\text{ SASSY}\\ \hline
\text{  DEPLETION }&\text{ REDUCTION}\\ \hline
\text{  TRANSLOCATED}&\text{ TELEPORTED}\\ \hline
\text{  PERSECUTING}&\text{ OPPRESSING}\\ \hline
\text{  CONVULSION}&\text{ CONTRACTION}\\ \hline
\text{  COLLEGIATE}&\text{ SCHOLASTIC}\\ \hline
\text{  EXCELLENT}&\text{ WONDERFUL}\\ \hline
\text{  SIMILAR}&\text{ DIFFERENT}\\ \hline
\text{  STATUS}&\text{ STATE}\\ \hline
\text{  LACKEY}&\text{ MINION}\\ \hline
\text{  TRANSCENDENTALISTS}&\text{ VISIONARIES }\\ \hline
\text{  TOWERS}&\text{ TURRETS}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Hint 1

> What is a synonym of "inquire"?

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Perfect Inquirey Words™,Not Perfect Inquirey Words™
ABDICATED,ABDICATE
BOOGERS,BOOGER
BOSSY,SASSY
DEPLETION,REDUCTION
TRANSLOCATED,TELEPORTED
PERSECUTING,OPPRESSING
CONVULSION,CONTRACTION
COLLEGIATE,SCHOLASTIC
EXCELLENT,WONDERFUL
SIMILAR,DIFFERENT
STATUS,STATE
LACKEY,MINION
TRANSCENDENTALISTS,VISIONARIES
TOWERS,TURRETS
```

Comment: Is the (mis)spelling of Inquirey intentional?

Comment: Yes, Inquirey is the intended spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that a Perfect Inquirey Word is such that

> If you convert the word to ASCII and add the numerical values the result is always a perfect square.

Examples

> PERSECUTING converted to ASCII is 80 69 82 83 69 67 85 84 73 78 71 
>  80+69+82+83+69+67+85+84+73+78+71 = 841 = 29^2
>  STATUS converted to ASCII is 83 84 65 84 85 83
>  83+84+65+84+85+83 = 484 = 22^2
>  TRANSCENDENTALISTS converted to ASCII is 84 82 65 78 83 67 69 78 68 69 78 84 65 76 73 83 84 83
>  84+82+65+78+83+67+69+78+68+69+78+84+65+76+73+83+84+83 = 1369 = 37^2

Why are they called Perfect Inquirey

> "Perfect" for the perfect square and "Inquirey" could be a synonym for Asky which sounds like ASCII.

Bonus: Which is the Mega Perfect Inquirey Word

> I suspect this is STATUS because if we convert it to lower case, then convert to ASCII and add the values, the result is 676 which is also a perfect square.

Comment: Excellent! Can you tell me which word is MEGA Perfect Inquirey? :)

Comment: That is indeed a mega perfect word. Using the words from https://github.com/dwyl/english-words, there are only 133 Mega Perfect Inquirey words out of over 400,000